# Is the structure $(\omega,+,2^n)$ undecidable? 

Tags: lo.logic

Let $L$ be the first-order language with binary function symbol $+$, unary function symbol $E$. Let $T$ be the set of sentences over this language that are true in the natural numbers, with $+$ interpreted in the usual way, and $E(n$) interpreted as $2^n$. Is the set $T$ recursive?

Comment: Also asked here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349383/undecidability-of-the-structure-omega-2n

Comment: See these related questions:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/103896/beyond-presburger-arithmetic/103914, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/106551/is-this-fragment-of-arithmetic-on-p-infty-mathbb-z-decidable. 

Comment: Does anybody know a book / other resources about omega structures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Marty explained in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103896/beyond-presburger-arithmetic/103914#103914), this question is the central topic of the paper [On the expansion $\langle \mathbb{N},+,2^x\rangle$ of Presburger arithmetic](http://www.math.osu.edu/~friedman.8/pdf/0AppB072710.pdf), by Françoise Point, based on a joint proceedings paper with G. Cherlin on a result credited to Alexei L. Semenov.